# Jenkins test fails to open Excel

Tags: jenkins, x11

My Devs are complaining that, on a fresh installation of Jenkins 1.609, there is a build-test that apparently tries to open some data using Excel, and it fails with:

> Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:11.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

I wonder how Jenkins, as it runs inside Tomcat, can even know where (what client system) to try to open a windowing application on.

In any case, does anyone have a clue as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to unset the DISPLAY environment variable before starting Jenkins. This issue can be closed.